# Angle between column vectors after centring a semi-orthogonal matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, orthogonality

Given a set of $n$, $m$ dimensional orthonormal vectors $\mathbf x_1, ..., \mathbf x_n$, where $m \geq n$. Let $\boldsymbol\mu = (\mu_1, ..., \mu_m)$ be the means of the vectors along each dimension. Then for every $\mathbf x_i$, we subtract the means to centre each dimension.

$$\mathbf x_i=\mathbf x_i - \boldsymbol \mu$$

The question is how will this action impact the angles between the vectors? Intuitively I can imagine 2 and 3-dimensional cases, where the angle between two orthonormal vectors increases due to this operation. Can we mathematically show how the angles between the $\mathbf x_i$ get affected in the general case?

Starting with the inner product of any two vectors $\mathbf x_i-\boldsymbol \mu$ and $\mathbf x_j-\boldsymbol \mu$, we have

$$\langle\mathbf x_i-\boldsymbol \mu, \mathbf x_j-\boldsymbol \mu\rangle=\sum_{k=1}^m (x_{ik}-\mu_k)(x_{jk}-\mu_k)$$
$$=\sum_{k=1}^m(x_{ik}x_{jk}-x_{ik}\mu_k-\mu_kx_{jk}+\mu_k^2)$$
$$=\sum_{k=1}^m(-x_{ik}\mu_k-\mu_kx_{jk}+\mu_k^2)\qquad\because\sum x_{ik}x_{jk}=0$$
$$\langle\mathbf x_i-\boldsymbol \mu, \mathbf x_j-\boldsymbol \mu\rangle=\sum_{k=1}^m\mu_k(\mu_k-(x_{ik}+x_{jk}))$$

I get stuck here. Intuitively, the sum should be negative.

Comment: Typically, writing $\mu = \{\mu_1, ..., \mu_m\}$ would imply that $\mu$ is a set, but it seems that you want $\mu$ to be a vector. I would recommend using $(\cdots)$ or $[\cdots ]$ instead. Also, it looks like you tried to get a bold-faced $\mu$. The command that works for that is `\boldsymbol \mu` rather than `\mathbf \mu`.

Comment: Thanks. added chnages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $X$ denote the $m \times n$ matrix whose columns are $\mathbf x_1,\dots, \mathbf x_n$. Let $\mathbf e \in \Bbb R^n$ denote the (column-)vector $\mathbf e = (1,\dots,1)$. The average $\boldsymbol \mu$ can be expressed as $\boldsymbol \mu = \frac 1n X \mathbf e$. Consequently, the matrix whose columns are the centered vectors $\mathbf y_i = \mathbf x_i - \boldsymbol \mu$ can be expressed as
$$
Y = X - \boldsymbol \mu \mathbf e^T = X - \frac 1n X \mathbf {ee}^T.
$$
The inner-product $\langle \mathbf y_i,\mathbf y_j \rangle = \mathbf y_i^T \mathbf y_j$ is the $i,j$ entry of the matrix $Y^TY$. Ultimately, any question you have regarding these inner products can be answered by considering this matrix.

We can also expand the product $Y^TY$ to find (using $I$ to denote the identity matrix) that
$$
Y^TY = [X - \boldsymbol \mu \mathbf e^T]^T[X - \boldsymbol \mu \mathbf e^T] = \\
X^TX - \mathbf e \boldsymbol \mu^TX - X^T\boldsymbol \mu\mathbf e^T + \mathbf e^T\boldsymbol \mu^T\boldsymbol \mu \mathbf e^T = \\
X^TX - \frac 1n \mathbf e \mathbf e^TX^TX - \frac 1n X^TX\mathbf e\mathbf e^T + (\boldsymbol \mu ^T\boldsymbol \mu)\mathbf{ee}^T = \\
I - \frac 1n \mathbf e \mathbf e^TI - \frac 1n I\mathbf e\mathbf e^T + (\boldsymbol \mu ^T\boldsymbol \mu)\mathbf{ee}^T = \\
I + \left((\boldsymbol \mu ^T\boldsymbol \mu) - \frac 2n \right)\mathbf{ee}^T.
$$
The inner-product $\boldsymbol \mu ^T\boldsymbol \mu$ can be simplified to
$$
\boldsymbol \mu ^T\boldsymbol \mu = \frac 1{n^2}(X\mathbf e)^T(X\mathbf e)^T = \frac 1{n^2}\mathbf e^T X^TX \mathbf e = 
\frac 1{n^2}\mathbf e^T \mathbf e = \frac 1n.
$$
Plugging this into the above expression gives us that $Y^TY = I - \frac 1n \mathbf {ee}^T$. In other words, we find that
$$
\langle \mathbf y_i, \mathbf y_j \rangle = 
\begin{cases}
1 - \frac 1n & i = j\\
- \frac 1n & i \neq j.
\end{cases}
$$
Correspondingly, the length of any vector $\mathbf y_i$ is $\sqrt{1 - \frac 1n} = \sqrt{\frac{n-1}{n}}$, and the angle between any distinct vectors $\mathbf y_i,\mathbf y_j$ satisfies
$$
\cos(\theta) = \frac{\langle \mathbf y_i,\mathbf y_j\rangle}{\|\mathbf y_i\|\,\|\mathbf y_j\|} = \frac{-1/n}{(n-1)/n} = -\frac{1}{n-1}.
$$

---

Here's what the corresponding computation looks like if you wanted to continue with the approach you began, sticking to summations and avoiding the matrix formalism. For $i \neq j$, as you have correctly noted, we have
$$
\begin{align}
\langle \mathbf x_i - \boldsymbol \mu, \mathbf x_j - \boldsymbol \mu\rangle &= \sum_{k=1}^m(x_{ik}x_{jk} - x_{ik}\mu_k-\mu_kx_{jk}+\mu_k^2)\\
&= \sum_{k=1}^m x_{ik}x_{jk} -\sum_{k=1}^m x_{ik}\mu_k- \sum_{k=1}^m\mu_kx_{jk}+\sum_{k=1}^m \mu_k^2.
\end{align}
$$
Moreover, you are correct that orthonormality ensures that $\sum_{k=1}^m x_{ik}x_{jk} = 0$. Now, noting that $\mu_k = \frac 1n \sum_{p = 1}^n x_{pk}$, we have
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^m x_{ik}\mu_k &= 
\sum_{k=1}^m x_{ik}\frac 1n \sum_{p=1}^n x_{pk}
\\ & = \frac 1n\sum_{k=1}^m \sum_{p=1}^n x_{ik} x_{pk}
\\ & = \frac 1n \sum_{p=1}^n\sum_{k=1}^m x_{ik} x_{pk}
= \frac 1n \sum_{p=1}^n\delta_{ip} = \frac 1n.
%
\end{align}
$$
Similarly, $\sum_{k=1}^m x_{jk}\mu_k = \frac 1n$. Finally,
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^m \mu_k^2 &= 
\sum_{k=1}^m \frac 1n\left( \sum_{p=1}^n x_{pk}\right)\frac 1n\left( \sum_{q=1}^n x_{qk}\right)
\\ & = \frac 1{n^2}\sum_{k=1}^m\sum_{p=1}^n\sum_{q=1}^n x_{pk}x_{qk}
\\ & = \frac 1{n^2}\sum_{p=1}^n\sum_{q=1}^n \sum_{k=1}^m x_{pk}x_{qk}
\\ & = \frac 1{n^2}\sum_{p=1}^n\sum_{q=1}^n \delta_{pq} = \frac 1{n^2}\sum_{p=1}^n 1 = \frac 1{n^2}\cdot n = \frac 1n.
\end{align}
$$
The conclusion follows.

The advantage to using the matrix multiplication approach (or similarly, to using an "Einstein summation convention") is that all reordering of summations is implicitly accounted for by the associativity of matrix multiplication (or, for the summation convention, by the fact that the expression is order-agnostic).

---

A notable property of the matrix $Y$ that holds regardless of whether the columns $\mathbf x_i$ are orthogonal is that it necessarily has rank $m-1$, with a nullspace spanned by $\mathbf e$. To see that this is the case, it suffices to note that $\operatorname{rank}(A - B) \geq \operatorname{rank}(A) - \operatorname{rank}(B)$, and that
$$
Y \mathbf e = \left[X - \frac 1n X \mathbf {ee}\right]\mathbf e = X\mathbf e - \frac 1n X\mathbf e(\mathbf e^T\mathbf e) = X\mathbf e - X\mathbf e = 0.
$$
It follows that $Y^TY\mathbf e = 0$. Correspondingly, for any $i$, it holds that $\sum_{j=1}^n \langle \mathbf y_i,\mathbf y_j\rangle = 0$.